# A haunted dead giant is following me around Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

A dead giant has been following me around Skyrim. It first showed up at Pelagia farm, and I just thought to myself, “Well, a giant must've attacked some farmer and he was killed by the AI.” But, nope. He appeared just as I was walking out of Whiterun.

[image: here he is in front of Whiterun just so you know I'm not lying]

The weird thing is that he’s always empty.

My main question is: Has anyone else seen it, and what did I do to get the same dead giant to follow me everywhere?

Comment: In future, use the screenshot key instead of taking a cellphone picture of your monitor.

Answer (score 4):

Dead bodies appearing when you load an area is a fairly common bug in Skyrim, I've had it a lot with dragons (although it may just be confirmation bias in that I notice those corpses the easiest).

To fix this specific case, you can open the console (<kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd>) and click on the dead giant. Make double sure that it says you've selected the giant and not something else, then type `disable` or `markfordelete` and press enter. This should remove the giant.